# JPG as background in Activity produces memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, png, jpeg

my little App always crashed after the 5th or 6th screen-rotation. Two main layouts are defined, one for landscape one for portrait. After spending the whole day looking for the memory leak I found the problem: I had a JPG defined as background for the Main-Activity. After changing the JPG to a PNG the memory problem was solved.

The background was defined as drawable and was defined in main.xml.

The problem did not come when I tested the App under 2.2 (emulator) but with 2.3.1 (also emulator) the app crashed.

Can someone reproduce this problem?

---

Now I reduced my app to the following code:

```
package at.memtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MemTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    recycleImages();
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    recycleImages();
    super.onPause();
}


private void recycleImages() {
    final LinearLayout theView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    if (theView != null) {
        final BitmapDrawable background = (BitmapDrawable) theView.getBackground();
        if (background != null) {
            background.getBitmap().recycle();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now the memory stays constant...
Can you imaging that this is necessary to avoid memory leaks?
As I said above - the image I use as a background is a PNG with about 220K.

Comment: Isn't this calling recycleImages twice, once in OnPause and once in onDestroy?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it's the file format that's the problem? Try this out: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

It might be that you're just not running out of memory as fast with the PNGs.

Comment: Thanks but I read this several times. It took me a day to comment out most of the program code. The last thing I did was to change JPG to PNG and with that the heap stays constant... I know my solution sounds a bit weird but after rotating the screen (before that caused the problem) for about 100 times there is no crash anymore.

Comment: Oh man - you were right. I made another test: 15mins flipping the orientation back an forth wich means about 900 cycles and it crashed.

Bit with the following piece of code it's flipping since about 2h:

Comment: Sorry, comment was not complete:

Oh man - you were right. I made another test: 15mins flipping the orientation back an forth wich means about 900 cycles and it crashed.

But with the following piece of code it's flipping since about 2h:
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  System.gc();
 }

Can you believe that? Now the heap stays rather constant. You think my memory problem is only caused by the emulator?

Comment: I've been doing a lot of work on apps that handle tremendous amounts of images and I can assure you that this is not just an emulator problem. Check out logcat once you put your app on a device and you will see that the heap will be resized once in a while. Android guarantees 16MB heap space but most implementations will give you more if you need it. However, there is a limit. Once that limit is reached, you get a nice OutOfMemoryError. 

Also, NEVER rely on System.gc().

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem.
Instead of .jpg I used .png, that solved the problem.

Comment: I use png background image too, but I have the leak. So still troubles.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with a jpg background image making my app extremely slow on certain devices, too. Using a png didn't solve it for me though. I think it might have something to do with the high compression I chose for the image to save space which might have resulted in more effort for decompression at runtime.